# SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable returns data type = int when all values are null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatareader

The following code snippet:

```
using (DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {

        DataRow drow = schemaTable.Rows[i];

        string name = drow.Field<string>("ColumnName");
        string dataType = drow.Field<string>("DataTypeName");
        bool isNullable = drow.Field<bool>("AllowDBNull");
        int maxLength = drow.Field<int>("ColumnSize");
        int precision = drow.Field<short>("NumericPrecision");
        int scale = drow.Field<short>("NumericScale");

        DatabaseField field = new DatabaseField(name, dataType, isNullable, maxLength, precision, scale);
        fields.Add(field);

    }
}
```

where the SQL string variable is:

```
select a = 1, b = 'hello', c = null,  d = 1.2345
union all
select a = 2, b = 'bye', c = null,  d = 2.3
```

effectively returns field.DataType = "int" for the field named c. No value was provided in that field. My question is why "int" and not simply a null value? Why would "int' be favored over something else?

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with `SqlDataReader`.

The default data type of `NULL` returned by SQL Server is `int`, if there is no other deduced type.

You can prove this with the following

```sql
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT NULL AS SomeNull;', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad7a1a81181781f578154006a0130816)

Comment: And to force another type use `cast(null as <whatever>)` in your query.

Comment: I just wondered, why int, why not something else. I guess int is the simplest possible answer without inventing a new data type called "NoIdea".

Comment: Probably. I can't find any documentation on it, and it makes little difference as `NULL` implicitly converts to any other type.

Comment: I noted that the field named 'd' comes back with type = "decimal", as opposed to "float". Yes I know one cast it in the actual SQL, was just surprised that 'decimal' is favored over 'float'.

Comment: That at least is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#decimal-constants